# Kivy app crashes while using the plyer library

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

As you can see below I import the plyer camera and email function, when i call the email it opens the email function no problems and returns when im done, but when i call the camera function the app crashes immediately. I'm using it as per the examples but it crashes when i call the camera. Im using Python 2.7 and building it with the buildozer on my linux machine.
I have included the camera in the permissions and the read and write to internal storage.

```
def sendemail(self):

    email.send(text=self.ddata)

def camera(self,product):

    self.imagename = "testname"
    filepath = str((self.imagename) + ".jpg")

    try:
        camera.take_picture(filename=filepath,
                            on_complete=self.done)
    except NotImplementedError:
        pass

    def done(self, self.filepath):
            if(exists(self.filepath)):
                popup = MsgPopup("Picture saved!")
                popup.open()
            else:
                popup = MsgPopup("Could not save your picture!")
                popup.open()
```

Please help, i have been trying to sort out this issue for days.

Comment: You really should post a [mcve], but at least how us your `self.done()` method.

Comment: def done(self, self.filepath):
        if(exists(self.filepath)):
            popup = MsgPopup("Picture saved!")
            popup.open()
        else:
            popup = MsgPopup("Could not save your picture!")
            popup.open()

Comment: even if i make it "pass" with no action it still crashes.

Comment: That looks reasonable. Does the plyer camera code automatically put the saved image in  the usual directory for camera images? Or do you need to provide a path to a writable folder?

Comment: for now i just want to get access to the camera, so i have made it to just save the file in the same location as the main.py, im running on my android device, the other files i use and create work and reads and writes fine.

Comment: I suggest using the `logcat` command of `buildozer` (and capture the output), or use Android Studio to view the logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to get the camera working by using the build in kivy function.

```
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
```

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__camera__main__py.html